# Process is not killed even after swiping off from the recents screen

Tags: android, android-activity, process, android-lifecycle

I have a camera app with options like photo, video, bokeh. If I goto recent and swipe up from there and relaunch the app, then it should open at photo option again regardless of which option I was using before killing the app.  The issue if I open the settings page in it and then go to recents and swipe up from there, the process is not killed and then if I relaunch the app, it will start from the last used option instead of photos option.

I am extending the application class and using onSavedInstance in my main activity and camerasettings activity, but that should not stop the process from getting killed.

If i don't open settings and goto recent and swipe up, it works as designed and starts from the photos option. I am not able to understand why my process is not getting killed.

The process should get killed everytime when swiping off from the recents screen.

Comment: Are you sure there aren't 2 tasks in the Stack .. Add the Intent code with question how r u opening the Settings screen .

Comment: Hi, sorry but am i little newbie at android. I am sure there aren't two tasks in the stack. Yes I have a background service that persists and I am not setting any intent to launch my settings page. It's a fragment.